# Setting Environment Variables at the User level

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins setup where i want to configure the environment variable before building my pipeline. 
I can set the environment variable in the configure page and use it in Jobs. However, I can not give the Administrator permission to the user to set it up. In-order to set the Environment variable user should have the admin access.

I have taken a look into the Injecting Environment variable at the Job level by installing Environment inject plugin. In this case also, user has to come to the configuring the job and set up.

Please let me know if there is a way to have the external script file and set the environment variable through it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "**This project is parameterized**" option in jenkins job configure page and pass the arguments.

[image]

You can also have "**environment**" block in Jenkinsfile to declare all the variable.

```
environment { 
        CC = 'clang'
    }
```

Please follow the [link](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/) for more information.

Comment: Can you please help me in configuring Jenkinsfile?

Comment: I will consider CC as a variable and i want to use CC in the Build process. Let me know how this can be done

Comment: Need to create one external file which should have all these variable values and i want these values for a build

Comment: You can use the variable as ${env.CC}/${CC}

Answer (score 0):

please refer https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment

```
pipeline {
   agent none
   environment {
       field = 'some'
   }
   stages {
       stage ('Preparation') {
           agent { label 'master'}
           environment {
               JENKINS_PATH = sh(script: 'pwd', , returnStdout: true).trim()
           }
           steps {
               echo "Hello world"
               echo "PATH=${JENKINS_PATH}"
               sh 'echo "JP=$JENKINS_PATH"'
          }
      }
   }
}
```